# What are all the Magic the Gathering Arena expansion set abbreviations?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

I'm sorry if this isn't the correct exchange for this question, but I couldn't find anything I thought would work better.

In the Magic the Gathering Arena computer game's search function you are able to search with a filter that filters out all other expansions. For example {E:MID} will find all cards you own from the Inistrad : Midnight Hunt expansion and no other sets. The problem I'm having is figuring out what the other set abbreviations might be. I know STX for Strixhaven and ZNR for Zendikar Rising. I was wondering if there is a website with the entire list of abbreviations or if someone here could post them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This link](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Set#List_of_Magic_expansions_and_sets) will bring you to the list of sets on MTG Wiki. You can click on the table headers to sort by name, expansion code, or release date.

Comment: This is a classic [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) post.

Comment: @PhilipKendall "I was wondering if there is a website..." the OP asked for a castle. Are you saying they shouldn't get one?

Comment: I can't get the tone of my previous comment right, but it is not meant as a criticism of the question, only a criticism of the criticism of the answer.

Comment: @Philip Kendal This is not a "link only" answer. It describes where to go to find the info requested, so even if the link breaks it might well be useful. It is infavct the best kind odf answer possible to this question.

Comment: It also links to a resource that answers a subtly different question. Many of those expansions are *not* on Arena.